# Creating new table based on column matching

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new table based on whether values in two columns match each other. If working with the following:

```
df <- data.frame(player=c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
                 team=c('Mavs', 'Mavs', 'Mavs', 'Mavs', 'Suns', 'Suns', 'Suns', 'Suns'),
                 points=c(20, 22, 26, 30, 30, 5, 1, 5))
```

I want to first see what values in the "player" column match, and if they match, also check the "team" column, and if their values match there as well, then create something like the following

```
df2 <- data.frame(player=c("A", "B"),
                  MavsPoints1=c("20","26"),
                  MavsPoints2=c("22","30"),
                  SunsPoints1=c("30","1"),
                  SunsPoints2=c("5","5"))
```

where each player gets a new row created, and their corresponding points values are collapsed based on whether it was first or second in appearance. I am stuck with how to match both values to each other, and how to create a new row and columns off of that. Any help appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)

dcast(setDT(df), player~team+rowid(player, team), value.var = 'points')

   player Mavs_1 Mavs_2 Suns_1 Suns_2
1:      A     20     22     30      5
2:      B     26     30      1      5

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
   group_by(team, player)%>%
   mutate(nm = row_number())%>%
   pivot_wider(player, names_from = c(team, nm), values_from = points)

# A tibble: 2 × 5
# Groups:   player [2]
  player Mavs_1 Mavs_2 Suns_1 Suns_2
  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A          20     22     30      5
2 B          26     30      1      5


transform(df, team = paste(team, ave(player,player, team, FUN = seq), sep='_'))|>
  reshape(idvar = 'player',dir = 'wide',v.names = 'points', timevar = 'team', sep='_')
   player points_Mavs_1 points_Mavs_2 points_Suns_1 points_Suns_2
1:      A            20            22            30             5
2:      B            26            30             1             5
```